# Docker not starting with docker start command in 1.3

Tags: docker

Trying to use command to create and start docker:

```
docker create ubuntu 
f53fa53cfbfbf3a93525f9d73a45a1ca13f84a32bdd0585df942ada04afbc0c4

docker start f53fa53cfbfbf3a93525f9d73a45a1ca13f84a32bdd0585df942ada04afbc0c4
```

This just returns.

If i do

```
docker ps -a
```

Then, the container is shown in stopped state.

Answer (score 3):

The default command for the `ubuntu` image is `bash`, which, without input, exits immediately.

To get a terminal, you need to allocate a tty when creating the container and attach to it when you start the container:

```
docker create -t ubuntu
docker start -i <containerId>
```

Answer (score 0):

To start a docker container from Docker image we can use the following command

```
docker run -it ubuntu /bin/bash
```

For basic learning of docker you can follow this blog.
https://www.tadaay.com/blog/docker/